# MySQL Insert into table if combination of variables doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert values into table if a combination of two values doesn't exist in database already. I don't care about `anotherdata` (if they exist or not). Lets have a table like this:

```
+---+---+--------------+
| x | y | anotherdata  |
+---+---+--------------+
| 1 | 1 | some string  |
| 1 | 2 | string2      |
| 1 | 3 | string3      |
+---+---+--------------+
```

My solution is to first query the database if there is the given record:

```
SELECT * FROM map WHERE x = ? AND y = ?
```

And if `num_rows` is 0 then insert new record:

```
INSERT INTO table (x, y, anotherdata ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

If `num_rows` is greater than 0 then do nothing.

I can't use unique keys here because x and y aren't unique. Unique is just their combination. In addition I expect this table to have thousands of records and using multiple queries would be really slow.

Comment: Did you have a question? It's entirely possible to define a UNIQUE KEY on the combination of two (or more) columns. With a UNIQUE constraint defined, you could use an `INSERT IGNORE` statement, to insert only those rows that don't violate a UNIQUE constraint. If you did happen to care about `anotherdata`, then you could make use of an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement. But, it's not at all clear if you were asking a question, or just offering a status report.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use `UNIQUE KEY` on combination of two colums. Also your query should look like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (x, y, anotherdata ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```